# Access data row in getTooltipText(e) event?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg, dimple.js

I use the following chart:

```
var data = [
                    { Date: "2015-09-14", DayOfMonth: 14, Type: "Views", Amount: 0, y1: 10, },
                    { Date: "2015-09-15", DayOfMonth: 15, Type: "Likes", Amount: 1, y1: 15, },
                    { Date: "2015-09-16", DayOfMonth: 16, Type: "Likes", Amount: 2, y1: 35, },
                    { Date: "2015-09-17", DayOfMonth: 17, Type: "Likes", Amount: 3, y1: 20, },
                    { Date: "2015-09-18", DayOfMonth: 18, Type: "Views", Amount: 4, y1: 22, },
                    { Date: "2015-09-19", DayOfMonth: 19, Type: "Views", Amount: 5, y1: 22, },
                    { Date: "2015-09-20", DayOfMonth: 20, Type: "Views", Amount: 6, y1: 22, },
         ];


var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chart", svgWidth, svgHeight);
var chart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
var xAxis = chart.addCategoryAxis("x", "DayOfMonth");
xAxis.title = null;
xAxis.addOrderRule("Date");     
var yAxis = chart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Amount");
yAxis.title = null;

var series = chart.addSeries("Type", dimple.plot.area);
series.interpolation = "cardinal";      
series.getTooltipText = function(e) {
   // need access to Date here
};
```

In my tooltip I need the Date component of the row but I just get DayOfMonth and Amount.

Here is a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/93q8pewy/1/

**How can I get data from the original data Row in the Tooltip, e.g., I need to get `Date`?**

Comment: can you put this up on a fiddle

Comment: For data you can just put the json and reference it instead of the ajax call..its best to put a working fiddle else its very tough to fix just by looking at the code you have posted...unless someone has faced same problem sometime and he knows teh answer

Comment: Here is a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/93q8pewy/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the object `e` passed into the callback, there's a property called `key` which dimple is using to uniquely identify each point.  With that in mind, you could use this kludge:

```
series.getTooltipText = function (e) {
    var rV = "";
    data.forEach(function(d){ //<-- loop data
       var u = d.Type + '_' + d.DayOfMonth + '___'; //<-- recreate key
       if (u === e.key){ //<-- does it match?
           rV = d.Date;
       }
    });
    return [rV]; //<-- show date in tooltip
};
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/93q8pewy/3/).